# Is it possible to run SQL query once and include both detail output and a count by category?

Tags: sql, html-table, count, coldfusion

Is it possible run a SQL once and display the detailed output + the count of amount by name? The code below works as I wish, but it runs two queries, so this may not be so productive..

[image: Screen shot of output]

```
    <cfquery name="myta" datasource="zett"> 
    Select w.t_firstname, w.t_lastname, w.t_total
    from table_bst a, table_zr w
    where 1=1
    ....
    </cfquery> 


    <cfquery name="meto" datasource="zett"> 
    SELECT a.t_firstname as Firstname,  COUNT(*)  AS Status
    from table_bst a, table_zr w
    where 1=1
    ....
    </cfquery> 

        <cfif meto.recordcount EQ 0>
            <table><tr><td style="color:#FF0000">There is currently an error</td></tr></table>
        <cfelse>
            <cfoutput>
                <table>
                  <cfloop query="meto">
                  <cfset temp = ValueList(myta.status)
                 <tr><td>FirstnameList: <cfoutput>#ListLen(temp)#</cfoutput></td></tr>
                </table>
           </cfoutput>
        </cfif>
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank for the feedback. Correct one query is used to display all information in a table and one query just for the amount.. pls see attachment.  can you share an example so it will easier to understand? thx

Comment: It's difficult to tell which query column (w.t_id, a.t_qui, w.t_zur) is "First Name", "Last Name" and "Total". Please update your code so it matches the screen shot. Also, eliminate long CSS styles as aren't relevant to the issue.

Comment: What SQL dialect? MySQL has [FOUND_ROWS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

Comment: @Ageax updated, thx for your help

Comment: what end result do you want?

Comment: @CalroMendes - What's your DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, ...)? Supported SQL syntax varies by vendor.

Comment: This is absolutely data that could be pulled from the database in just a single query. You database type will probably change the syntax, but working with data is essentially what databases were made for. (And please don't use comma-syntax in your query. Look at `JOIN` syntax.)

Comment: And if you absolutely needed to, you could also just do a Query of Query to count what you need from the original query.

Comment: @Shawn using the query of query i getting an error saying that FROM myta doesn't exist... any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and ColdFusion-centric way of accomplishing what you are looking for is to simply use a query of query:

**MAIN QUERY:**

```
<cfquery name="myta" datasource="zett"> 
    SELECT w.t_firstname, w.t_lastname, w.t_total
    FROM table_bst a
    INNER (OR LEFT/RIGHT OUTER) JOIN table_zr w ON a.? = w.?
    WHERE
        [ 
          1=1 is only really useful if you have some sort of if/else logic in your 
          WHERE clause, and it's used to make sure there is a value there if none 
          of the if/else conditions are met.
        ]
        AND/OR [other stuff]
</cfquery>
```

**Query of Query:**

```
<cfquery name="meto" dbtype="query">
    SELECT t_firstname AS FirstName, count(*) AS Status
    FROM myta
    GROUP BY FirstName
</cfquery>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<table>
    <cfif meto.recordcount EQ 0>
        <tr><td style="color:#FF0000">There is currently an error</td></tr>
    <cfelse>
        <cfoutput query="meto">
            <tr>
                <td>#Firstname#:#Status#</td>
            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfif> 
</table>
```

https://trycf.com/gist/529c0bf10b7c6d7420eae399572744bb/lucee5?theme=monokai